# Java - Sorting out an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am encountering some slight and stupid issue while trying to sort out my arrays.
So here's what I'm doing and what I want to do :

I generate an array of ints (good ol' t = new int[];) filled with random generated numbers from -1 to 9. The size of the array is irrelevant. I would like to make so that each "-1" will get to the end of the array while every other will get "pushed" to take the place.

As I'm not a native english speaker it's really hard to express myself correctly on this.

Example : 
my array is : 9 2 -1 4 6 -1
I want : 9 2 4 6 -1 -1

I currrently managed to get this BUT it won't work if there are two consecutives -1 cause the second one will get swapped.

Ex :
Initial : 9 2 -1 -1 4 6
After modif : 9 2 -1 4 6 -1

As I said the problem is probably really near from being solved but I really can't find a fix right now.

Here's my code :

```
    for(int i=0;i<NB_CARD;i++)
    {
        t[i]=randomGenerator.nextInt(10)-1;
        System.out.print("t["+i+"]= "+t[i]+"\t\t");
        if(i==4){System.out.println("");}
    }

    //each -1 should be at the end of array
    for(int i=0;i<NB_CARD;i++)
    {
        int tmp=0;

        if(t[i]==-1) 
        {
            for(int y=i;y<NB_CARD-1;y++)
            {
                    tmp=t[y+1];
                    t[y+1]=t[y];
                    t[y]=tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<NB_CARD;i++)
    {
        System.out.print("t["+i+"]= "+t[i]+"\t\t");
        if(i==4){System.out.println("");}
    }
```

Thank you in advance for every tip/help that could lead me to solve this

Comment: This is a really inefficient way of doing this.  Do you have to use nested loops?

Comment: well I come from C so that's the first solution that came to my mind. I'm only into java since yesterday, the language probably have possibilities that I ignore of.

Comment: how about using Collections.sort().  In comparator, you can can define the sort order you like.

Comment: If you look at my answer, it would be much the same in C as well.

Comment: @JamaDjafarov as the OP is not actually sorting ;)

Comment: it is sorting. The task is to sort negative and positive numbers. The rule is: if number is positive do nothing, negative move right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more efficient way of doing this with one loop is.

```
int j = 0;
// copy all the non -1 values down.
for (int i = 0; i < NB_CARD; i++)
    if (t[i] != -1)
       t[j++] = t[i];
// fill the rest with -1
Arrays.fill(t, j, NB_CARD, -1);
```

if `NB_CARD == t.length` you can do

```
int[] t = {3, -1, -1, -1, 4, 5, 6, -1, -1};
int j = 0;
// copy all the non -1 values down.
for (int i : t)
    if (i != -1)
       t[j++] = i;
// fill the rest with -1
Arrays.fill(t, j, t.length, -1);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(t));
```

prints

```
[3, 4, 5, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
```

In Java 8 you can do this

```
int[] t = {6, -1, -1, -1, 4, 5, 3, -1, -1};
List<Integer> sorted = IntStream.of(t).boxed()
        .sorted((a, b) -> (a > -1 ? 1 : 0) - (b > -1 ? 1 : 0))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++)
    t[i] = sorted.get(i);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(t));
```

which prints

```
[6, 4, 5, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
```

though it is O(N log N) instead of O(N) and has more code.

Comment: Yep, sounds good. Thank you very much, I guess I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: @JuofAstora a common early mistake is assuming that you can master programming in months or years, a second common mistake is to assume others know more than you do when in fact we are all learning.  I have only been programming Java for 16 years ;)

Comment: For the input array [3, -1, -1, -1, 4, 5, 6, -1, -1] this returns [3, 4, 5, 6, -1, 5, 6, -1, -1]. Two `-1`s were removed and extra `5` and `6` were inserted in their places.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak thank you for pointing that out. It is the `toIndex` not the `length` you need to provide.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)), supplying your own Comparator that puts -1 at the end of the output.

Comment: `sort` is not appropriate here as the OP is not trying to sort the entries, just shift all the -1 to the end.

Comment: Missed this, but it would still work since sort is stable and if the comparator returns 0 for any non -1 values.

Comment: It's also O(n*log(n)), whereas it's doable in O(n).

Comment: @pmorken good point, though you have the problem that `T` is an `int` not `Integer` which is easily solved.

Comment: I've been happily ignoring this kind of thing since the advent of autoboxing (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the array into list, iterate over list and remove all -1, counting how many you removed. Then add that many at the end of the list. If the end result has to be an array, you can use List.toArray method to convert it back.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] t = {3, -1, -1, -1, 4, 5, 6, -1, -1};

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.addAll(list, t);

    int numberOfMinusOnes = 0;
    for (Integer number : list) {
        if (number == -1) {
            numberOfMinusOnes++;
        }
    }

    list.removeAll(Arrays.asList(-1));

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMinusOnes; i++) {
        list.add(-1);
    }

    list.toArray(t);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(t));
}
```

Some of boiler plate code can be simplified using google collections library. I would also advise to extract some parts into separate methods to increase readability.

Comment: You don't need to count how many were removed, you can Array.fill the rest of the array with `-1`

Comment: hm, sounds pretty clever. I guess, I'll try that. I don't really know what a list is but It shouldn't be hard to find infos on that topic.

Comment: @Peter: My suggested solution uses List so the elements will be shifted. If you want to operate on the array, you will have to do shifts manually, but at the end of the array you will have original values - when using Arrays.fill you will have to specify the range so you still need to count all -1s.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak if you look at my answer, there is no counting of the `-1`s

Comment: @PeterLawrey: There is, your j++ is counting all non `-1`s what is equivalent to counting `-1`s

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak true, but it not something which is extra, I have to do `j++` anyway.

Comment: @PeterLawrey In every solution we have to do some counting like this, anyway I think your solution is better - shorter and cleaner ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the code correctly, if you find a `-1`, you eventually bubble it up to the end.

What you could do, would be to store the location of the *current* last element, which at the beginning would be `n - 1`.

When you find a `-1`, you could replace the `i`th element with the *current* last element and then, decrease the value of *current* by 1. This should allow you to always put any new `-1` elements you encounter at the end.

Code wise:

```
    int[] t = new int[5];
    t[0] = -1; t[1] = -1; t[2] = 4;

    t[3] = -1;  //Just for demonstration purposes
    t[4] = -1;  //Just for demonstration purposes

    int currentLast = 0;

    for(int i = t.length - 1; i >=0; i--)
    {
        if(t[i] == -1)            
            currentLast = i - 1;
        else
            break;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < t.length; i++)
        System.out.println(t[i]);

    System.out.println("After");


    for(int i = 0; i < currentLast; i++)
    {
        if(t[i] == -1)
        {   
            int temp = t[currentLast];
            t[currentLast] = t[i];
            t[i] = temp;
            currentLast--;
        }
    }

     for(int i = 0; i < t.length; i++)
        System.out.println(t[i]);
}
```

Yields:

```
-1
-1
4
-1
-1
After
4
-1
-1
-1
-1
```

Comment: This solution won't work if there are two -1s at the end of initial array. if(t[currentLast]== -1) currentLast--; should be a loop.

Answer (score 0):

**Using bubble sort**

```
package com.appkart.collections;

import java.util.Random;

public class Test {

    public void fillRandomNumber(int a[]) {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = random.nextInt(10)-1;
        }
    }

    public void printNumber(int a[]) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length ;i++) {
            System.out.print(a[i] +" ");
        }
    }

    //Using bubble sort
    public void sortRandomNumber(int a[]) {
        int length = a.length;
        int temp;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < length - i; j++) {
                if (a[j - 1] < a[j]) {
                    temp = a[j - 1];
                    a[j - 1] = a[j];
                    a[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a[] = new int[10];
        Test test = new Test();
        test.fillRandomNumber(a);
        System.out.println("Random Number bofore sort");
        test.printNumber(a); 
        test.sortRandomNumber(a);
        System.out.println("\n Random Number after sort");
        test.printNumber(a); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
int[] a = { 9, 2, -1, 4, 6, -1 };
for(int i=a.length-1; i>0; i--)
{
    for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
    {
        if(a[i] < a[j])
        {
            int jvalue = a[j];
            a[j] = a[i];
            a[i] = jvalue;
        }
    }
}
```